# Why my script at the bottom of body blocks the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I read that if I put the script at the bottom of the body the page would not block because will first render the html above. But it dose not happens to me, even if it is at the end is blocked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Some document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <p>blah blah</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hi");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why??

Update:
doesn't work in chrome.
Works in firefox.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Since `<script>` elements could include `document.write`, they block the parsing of HTML that appears after the script element until the script has been executed. This is most significant when the HTML includes instructions to download other things over the network (since you add the delay from downloading and running the JS to the delay for downloading the image or whatever).

What is blocked in **this** example is the painting of the viewport, not the parsing of the HTML. Putting the script at the end doesn't stop that being blocked since the browser only repaints the viewport periodically and not on every single DOM change.